# Display PHP output in HTML using JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So currently I am working on a simple login authentication. I have an HTML page and PHP script using cURL to authenticate against a website. What I want to do is, instead of after user input pressing submit and switching to the PHP page for the "correct" "Incorrect" echo, I want JS to just give a small message under the submit button giving that message so they can enter info again.

Thank you it was fixed and working now thank you shyju

Comment: Check developers console please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to stop the default behavior for the button submit(posting the form the the page without ajax). Try jQuery `preventDefault` method.

```
$(function(){
  $("#sub").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     //now post the form using ajax to the server page for validation
      $.post($("#login").attr("action"), $("#login :input").serializeArray(),
                                                                  function(info){
          $("#result").html(info);
          clearInput();
      });

  });
});
```

Comment: I am really sorry! It is removed now! There was a competition over at Code Golf about JS snippets destroying SO. They shouldn't actually do any permanent damage, but one of them did trigger a click on the down vote button... I suspected one of them did do damage, and so I checked it afterwards so that the harm could be undone! Anyway, this is a good answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

You should do the call using AJAX instead of submitting the form.

In your case, you might want to use jQuery's [post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).